# Django - 'bool' object is not callable

Tags: django

I have a UserProfile Model that looks like this:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user        = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='profile',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    needhelp    = models.BooleanField(default=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return ('user:help', (), {'id': self.id})
```

Im working on a visual guide for a website and for a start I made a modal that asks the user if he needs help when he logs in.

If he clicks "no" I want to change the needhelp bool to False and hide the modal.
If he clicks "yes" I want to change the needhelp bool to True and start the guide.

This is how far I got:

```
class HelpToggle(RedirectView):
    def get_redirect_url(self, pk, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, pk=pk)
        url_ = obj.get_absolute_url()
        user = self.request.user
        if user.is_authenticated():
            if user in obj.needhelp.all():
                user.needhelp = False
            else:
                user.needhelp = True
        return url_
```

---

```
url(r'^help/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', HelpToggle.as_view(),name="help")
```

---

But when I go to the url, I get 'bool' object is not callable

Thank you for any help

Comment: Not sure what you are trying here `obj.needhelp.all()`? `obj.needhelp` will return `True` or `False`

Comment: You are searcing user in needhelp object.
Modify to  `if user in user.objects.all():`  instead of    `if user in obj.needhelp.all():`

Comment: To get all the objects: use <Model_Name>.objects.all(), I modified the comment

Comment: In your case, use `if user in UserProfile.objects.all():`

Comment: @drd now I get: quote_from_bytes() expected bytes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203177/discussion-between-drd-and-user9023).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to get the `profile` that is linked to the request user. Then check that profile's `needhelp` field. If that is the case you can do something like this.

```
class HelpToggle(RedirectView):
    def get_redirect_url(self, pk, *args, **kwargs):
        user = self.request.user
        obj = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, user=user)
        url_ = obj.get_absolute_url()

        if user.is_authenticated:
            if obj.needhelp:
                obj.needhelp = False
            else:
                obj.needhelp = True
        return url_
```

Try updating your `get_absolute_url` to call `reverse` name as below

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('help', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still get: 'bool' object is not callable

Comment: I removed the parenthesis from `is_authenticated`. It should work now.

Comment: Now I get: quote_from_bytes() expected bytes

Comment: That issue is caused by your redirect view. We need to fix that next

Comment: Now I get 'pk' is not defined

Comment: Sorry should be `self.pk`

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely caused by the call to `user.is_authenticated()`.  As per the Django documentation (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/auth/), `is_authenticated` is a read-only attribute, not a method to be called. So your check should be just:

```
if user.is_authenticated:
```

Comment: I removed the parenthesis but still the same issue

Comment: You also need to address the `needhelp` problem, which everyone else already mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Use is_authenticated not is_authenticated(), also your decision is not depend on your obj.needhelp, it depends on your user reaction, so get it and compare it like this code,

```
 class HelpToggle(RedirectView):
    def get_redirect_url(self, pk, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, pk=pk)
        url_ = obj.get_absolute_url()
        user = self.request.user
        if user.is_authenticated:

            needhelp = # get the user clicked data, what he want, yes or no that means True or False

            if needhelp == True:
                user.needhelp = True
            else:
                user.needhelp = False
        return url_
```